# A count of something inside an INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I had a table of machines our employees use called `machineManufacturer`, which had the columns `ID`, and `manufacturer`. Then, I had another table that was added to whenever that machine was used called `deviceUsage`, which has the columns `ID`, and `date`.

I want to know the number of times used grouped according to manufacturer.

I believe the answer has something to do with `COUNT` and an `INNER JOIN`, but I am fairly new to SQL (only took one databases class in school).

I have tried something like:

```
SELECT manufacturer
FROM machineManufacturer
INNER JOIN deviceUsage
ON machineManufacturer.ID = deviceUsage.ID
```

which returns a big column of manufacturers, without any count. I am trying to count them and get a table like--

```
Manufacturer: Count
Dell: 30
HP: 27
Mac: 9
Lenovo: 14
etc.
```

Any comments welcome. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `group by`:

```
SELECT MF.manufacturer, count(*)
FROM machineManufacturer MF INNER JOIN
     deviceUsage D
     ON MF.ID = D.ID
GROUP BY MF.manufacturer;
```